Why do we get an error in Next.js when using React-bootstrap Card without including 'use client'?
when I use the react-bootstrap Card element in a next.js project, I get
"Unhandled Runtime Error Error:* Could not find the module "C:\my-project\node_modules\react-bootstrap\esm\Card.js#default#Body" in the React Client Manifest. This is probably a bug in the React Server Components bundler." I can fix the error by using "use client".*
What is the reason I am getting this error in Card element? I want to understand the reason for this. I am waiting for your help. Thanks
code
I solved the problem by using "use client" to work on client side, but I wonder what I need to use it here?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

You already answered the your question I solved the problem by using "use client", Bootestrap's Card uses client-only APIs
